# Infinity-to-one function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, infinity, spheres

Are there continuous functions $f:I\to S^2$ such that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is infinite for every $x\in S^2$?

Here, $I=[0,1]$ and $S^2$ is the unit sphere.

I have no idea how to do this.

Note: This is not homework! The question came up when I was thinking about something else.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what motivated him/her to downvote this question?

Comment: How about the composition of (i) a space-filling curve from $[0,1]$ to the unit ball, and (ii) a projection from the unit ball to its boundary $S^2$?

Comment: The reason this came up is, I was wondering why my book had such a complicated proof that the sphere is simply connected (every loop can be retracted to a point). Then I realized, maybe it's hard to prove because some loops are very complicated.

Comment: @Rahul You will have problems with mapping the ball's center, unless you have an idea on how to avoid that.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Your realization is spot on. The complicated first step of the proof of simple connectivity is designed to reduce to the case that $f : I \to S^2$ is not surjective, by constructing a path homotopy from an arbitrary $f$ to a nonsurjective $f$.

Comment: @LeeMosher The proof I know basically partitions the loop into finitely many nonsurjective pieces (_Algebraic Topology_ by Hatcher), but I'm guessing it's equivalent to the proof you're talking about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider a space filling curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow I^2$, the projection $q: I^2 \rightarrow S^2$ given by the quotient topology on the square that furnishes the sphere, and the projection $\pi: I^2 \rightarrow I$ on the first coordinate.

The map $q \circ \gamma \circ \pi \circ \gamma$ satisfies what you want.

Comment: So $\pi\circ\gamma$ is an infinity-to-one function from $I\to I$, and $q\circ\gamma$ is a surjective function from $I$ to $S^2$?

Comment: @AkivaWeiberger Yes. Maybe the usual construction of a space-filling curve already gives a infinity-to-one function (I believe this is the case), but since I don't remember the details well enough, I prefered to make this workaround.

Comment: I doubt the usual ones (ex: Hilbert and Peano curves) are infinity-to-one, though I encourage you to post it as a question.

Comment: Check out this related question: [Countable-infinity-to-one function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1599921/166353)

Comment: If you use the usual  construction, shown in  many books, for a continuous surjection $g : I\to I^2$  then the composite  $p= q g,$ where  $q$ is projection to first co-ordinate, then for any nbhd $B$ of any $t\in I$,  the cardinal of $ \{s\in B :p(s)=p(t)\}$ is the cardinal of the reals. And $p$ is nowhere differentiable